# update parent version to next release version

Tags: maven

http://mojo.codehaus.org/versions-maven-plugin/update-properties-mojo.html

The Maven versions plugin `versions:update-parent` only updates to the latest snapshot or release version.

However, I am currently on 1.1-SNAPSHOT and I have 1.1 and 2.0 versions of this parent. How can I update to 1.1?

NOTE: This is not a multi-module project. The parent is a company/project wide pom all projects inherit.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

I got the same problem as you, but finally understood it was only accepting a range as input, not a single value, so in your case you should put:

> mvn versions:update-parent -DparentVersion=[1.0,1.1]

This should select 1.1 if it exists in your repository.

Got the clue reading tickets in [plugin bug tracker](http://jira.codehaus.org/browse/MVERSIONS-158?jql=project%20=%20MVERSIONS%20AND%20text%20~%20%22parentVersion%22)

Comment: a solution but it's a pitty maven versions does support a use-next-parent-version goal

Answer (score 6):

This works:

```
mvn versions:update-parent -DparentVersion=[1.1]
```

The reason is : because the parentVersion property **is expected to be a range**, not a single version.

Then you can set "`-DparentVersion=[14,16)`" as documented in versions-maven-plugin, but if you want to set a given version (eg 1.0), you must define a range with only one result, using bounding brackets : [1.0].

See versions range specification: http://maven.apache.org/enforcer/enforcer-rules/versionRanges.html

This also works for a `-SNAPSHOT` version if you don't forget to set allowSnapshots=true

Comment: Thanks for giving the link to the documentation on the versioning rules

Answer (score 0):

For a more automated approach you can use the `build-helper:parse-version` helper, so you can update to the next-parent-version (you still need to know what part is "next"). For example, next parent minor:

```
mvn build-helper:parse-version versions:update-parent -DparentVersion='[${parsedVersion.majorVersion}.${parsedVersion.nextMinorVersion}]'
```